# Show data from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I created a arraylist as below:

```
ArrayList<String> mtsData3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    mtsData3.add("1");
    mtsData3.add("2");
    mtsData3.add("3");
    mtsData3.add("4");
    mtsData3.add("5");
    mtsData3.add("6");
    mtsData3.add("7");
    mtsData3.add("8");
```

And my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        LinearLayout ll4 = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll4.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lllp4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(SCREEN_WIDTH/5, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll4.setLayoutParams(lllp4);

        ll3.addView(ll4);

        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++){
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpTlB = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(SCREEN_WIDTH/5, SCREEN_HEIGHT/20);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lpTlB);
            tv.setText(mtsData3.get(i2));
            ll4.addView(tv);
        }
    }
```

Now, I am getting only 1 and 2 values from ArrayList. I want all values from ArrayList.

Here's what I am getting:

```
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
```

And Here's what I want:

```
1   3   5   7
2   4   6   8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++) {
    ...
    tv.setText(mtsData3.get(i2));
    ...
}
```

With this, `i2` can flip back and forth between values 0 and 1. That is why you were getting 1,2,1,2...

You can have a separate variable for indexing into the list

```
...
int index = 0;
for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++) {
    ...
    tv.setText(mtsData3.get(index++));
    ...
}
```

`mtsData3.get(index++)` - It gets the value at index `index` from `mtsData3` and increments `index`.